# Internet Explorer drops "this site is not secure" whenever opening the Syncthing web app

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ssl-certificate, security-warning

On a machine where I don't have any admin privileges, I have installed [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/). But whenever I start/restart the software I get this warning in IE:

> This site is not secure

> Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA

> DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CN_INVALID

I have tried many things on the internet with no avail. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.1.** We have to use Internet Explorer as it is imposed by the company.

**P.S.2.** My machine is Windows 10 Version 1803, and Internet Explorer 11.1304

Comment: Have you added the certificate to your Trust Store for the user

Comment: @Ramhound I'm a novice and don't know how to do that! May you be kind to explain in a step by step way I can follow?

Comment: You really should ask your IT Administrator to do this.  I don't know if you have permissions to add a self-signed certificate to your certificate store.

Comment: @Ramhound maybe we can try? If you provide the steps I can go forward and tell you if it worked or not.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable giving you commands that will change the configuration of a machine owned and administrated by your company.

Comment: This is because Syncthing's web server uses a self-signed certificate. This error doesn't break anything; it's just your browser's way of telling you that it doesn't know who issued the certificate. (The "This site is not secure" is a bit misleading; it doesn't mean the traffic isn't encrypted.)